# How to modify builder pattern by adding more keys?

Tags: java, enums, builder

I am working on a project in which I need to make a keys by passing different parameters to it so I decided to use Builder pattern here.

Below is my `DataKey` class builder which we need to make before calling the code. In the below builder class, we have three important keys which are `userId`, `uuid` and `deviceId`.

```
public final class DataKey {

    private final long userId;
    private final long uuid;
    private final long deviceid;
    private final int clientId;
    private final long timeout;

    private DataKey(Builder builder) {
        this.userId = builder.userId;
        this.uuid = builder.uuid;
        this.deviceid = builder.deviceid;
        this.clientId = builder.clientId;
        this.timeout = builder.timeout;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        protected final long userId;
        protected final long uuid;
        protected final long deviceid;
        protected final int clientId;
        protected long timeout = 200L;          

        public Builder setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setUuid(String uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
            return this;
        }


        public Builder setDeviceId(String deviceid) {
            this.deviceid = deviceid;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setClientId(String clientId) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
            return this;
        }

        public DataKey build() {
            return new DataKey(this);
        }
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public long getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public long getDeviceId() {
        return deviceid;
    }

    public int getclientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public long getTimeout() {
        return timeout;
    }       
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Here customer, will pass `modelId` always but they can  pass us  different combinations of important id keys such as -

- `userId, uuid, deviceId` : If they are passing `userId`, `uuid` and `deviceId`, then the  preference will be `userId`. So now, I will use `userId` and that means, it is a `USERFLOW` as shown in the below enum.
- `uuid, deviceId` : If they are passing `uuid` and `deviceId`, then the  preference will be `uuid`. So now, I will use `uuid` and that means, it is a `DEVICEFLOW` as shown in the below enum.
- `deviceId` : If they are passing `deviceId`, then the  preference will be `deviceId` since that is the only important key they have passed. So now, I will use `deviceId` and that means, it is a `DEVICEFLOW` as shown in the below enum.

So in short, `userId` takes the priority first, then `uuid` and then `deviceId`.

**They cannot call us by only passing `clientId`, some important key has to be there, either `userId` or `uuid` or `deviceId`.**

```
userId is a long (which is USERFLOW)
uuid is a String (which is DEVICEFLOW)
deviceId is a String (which is DEVICEFLOW)
```

I also have created an enum which is -

```
public enum FlowEnum {
    USERFLOW, DEVICEFLOW
}
```

I also need to add which enum type we are about to serve in my `DataKey` class as well depening on what "id" gets prioritized. Since FlowEnum is opaque to customer who is making keys.

Below is the way I can think of people will make the keys but how do I make sure that they are  passing atleast one id keys from userId, uuid and deveiceid?

```
DataKey keys = new DataKey.Builder().setUserId(foo).setUuid(blaah).setDeviceId(foopes).setClientId(123).addTimeout(100L).build();
```

Below is my simple Task class which implements Callable and does all the work -

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private final DataKey keys;

    public Task(DataKey keys) {
        this.keys = keys;   
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        // print whether it is USERFLOW or DEVICEFLOW?
        // print which id keys I should use here?

    }   
}
```

Comment: Bro, you should summarize your question - that's way too long...

Comment: sure.. let me try summarizing it :(

Comment: Now, as for your question, augment `build()` method to validate what you want (throw an exception if the user passed only clientId etc)

Comment: @alfasin If you have understood the question, how would I add other id keys in my class? And then how would customer will call us?

Comment: augment `Builder` with additional set-methods: `new DataKey.Builder(userId, clientId).addTimeout(100L).addKey1(k1).addKey2(k2)...`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am already doing right? What my question is, they can pass userId, uuid and deviceId, three different keys together and then I need to prioritize it and  pick one from it. So If I go with your suggestion, you have a default builder  constructor which takes userId, sometimes, they won't pass userId and they can pass only uuid and deviceid right?

Comment: Either augment build() method to validate what you want, add logic for prioritizations etc. Or do it in `DataKey` constructor.

Comment: @alfasin Sure, the only confusion I have is, how do I add validation in the build method. Can you provide a simple example for this basis on my example. Meaning how can I do the validation in build method and prioritization? Thanks for the help. I am pretty new to Builder pattern as of now so getting little confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start by adding your enum to `DataKey`:

```
public final class DataKey {

    private long userId =0L;
    private long uuid =0L;
    private long deviceid =0L;
    private int clientId =0;
    private long timeout =0L;

    // add enum:
    private final FlowEnum flow;
    // then add getter etc...
```

and now update the constructor:

```
private DataKey(Builder builder) {
    this.userId = builder.userId;
    this.uuid = builder.uuid;
    this.deviceid = builder.deviceid;
    this.clientId = builder.clientId;
    this.timeout = builder.timeout;

    if (userId == 0 && uuid == 0 && deviceId == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You have to pass at least one" +
          " of the following: userId, uuid or deviceId");
    }
    if (userId != 0) {
        this.flow = FlowEnum.USERFLOW;
    }
    else {
        this.flow = FlowEnum.DEVICEFLOW;
    }
}
```

Then later-on:

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private final DataKey keys;

    public Task(DataKey keys) {
        this.keys = keys;   
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        // print whether it is USERFLOW or DEVICEFLOW? 
        System.out.println(keys.getFlow());

    }   
}
```

Comment: userId is long here so we cannot do null check I guess, getting compilation error in my code.

Comment: So remove the `final` and declare it with an "init value" then override it in the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I just did 0 check and it worked fine after that. Now I also need to validate that they are passing atleast one "id" keys either userId, uuid or deviceid? How would I validate this step? They cannot call us by  simply passing `clientId`.

Comment: @user2809564 see the validation in the constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked fine so far. One last question, regarding prioritization where that code should be added?

Comment: @user2809564 setting the enum `this.flow = FlowEnum.USERFLOW;` *is* the prioritization.